# Automating my slider

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, jsfiddle

I have an image slider with an hover effect build into my Website. (click here for my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nctfa/).

HTML:

```
<div class="accordian">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="image_title">   <a href="#">TERA Online</a>

        </div>  <a href="#">
            <img src="http://spieletrend.com/screenshots/tera-release-termin.jpg"/>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image_title">   <a href="#">Diablo 3</a>

        </div>  <a href="#">
            <img src="http://www.airbornegamer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/diablo-3-HD-wallpaper-640x320.jpg"/>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image_title">   <a href="#">Assassin's Creed</a>

        </div>  <a href="#">
            <img src="http://totalgame.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Assassins-Creed-4-Black-Flag.jpg"/>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image_title">   <a href="#">Grand Theft Auto V</a>

        </div>  <a href="#">
            <img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/448/977/448977532_640.jpg"/>
        </a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image_title">   <a href="#">Battlefield 4</a>

        </div>  <a href="#">
            <img src="http://stickskills.com/omega/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Battlefield4-e1366202710731.jpg"/>
        </a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
color:#fff;
}
.accordian {
    width: 805px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.accordian ul {
    width: 2000px;
}
.accordian li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.accordian ul:hover li {
    width: 40px;
}
.accordian ul li:hover {
    width: 640px;
}
.accordian li img {
    display: block;
}
.image_title {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 640px;
}
.image_title a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I want to automatically change the highlighted picture while i am not hovering it (like this: http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/).

Is it possible, to do that without affecting the img tags at all?

Thanks,
Thorkel

Comment: Setting a timeout in the hover handler might be the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/Nctfa/28/

I'd suggest having a class (I've used `shown`) that rotates around your slides:

```
var ulElem = $('.accordian').find('ul');

function rotate() {

    var next = ulElem.find('.shown').removeClass('shown').next();

    if (next.length) {
        next.addClass('shown');
    } else {
        ulElem.find('li').eq(0).addClass('shown');
    }
}

// i just wrapped this in a setTimeout so the slides are briefly shown 
// equally spaced at the start, but you could just jump right into it
setTimeout(function () {
    ulElem.addClass('shown');
    ulElem.find('li').eq(0).addClass('shown');
    setInterval(rotate, 1800);
}, 1800);
```

But then using CSS to not only show the `.shown` element, but also to ignore the `shown` class when the `ul` element is being hovered over:

```
.accordian ul.shown:not(:hover) li {
    width: 40px;
}
.accordian ul:not(:hover) li.shown {
    width: 640px;
}
```

by using the `:not` selector:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

But note that `:not` won't work for IE6-8:

http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

So if you care about them, you'll need to use events to track the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a plugin for jQuery called [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) that does what you describe.

This will solve your problem

moreover we can try to delay the hover effect using  [Delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

[Check this demo fiddle using delay](http://jsfiddle.net/Nctfa/3/)

like this

```
$('.accordian').hover(function(){
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.accordian').delay(200).css('color','red');
    }, 2000);    
});
```

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong. 

I want to automatically change the highlighted picture while i am not hovering it (like this: [link](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/) ).

Is it possible, to do that without affecting the img tags at all?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

Ok. So you want a script that change the picture like a carousel.

First you should do it in javascript, and for this you cannot use the pseudoclass `:hover`.
It's better to use a simple class `hover` for example

```
.accordian ul.hover li {
    width: 40px;
}
.accordian ul li.hover {
    width: 640px;
}
```

Now you should use javascript in order to have the same effect.

```
function _hover() {
    $(this).addClass('hover'); 
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
}
function _out() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover'); 
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
}

var $lis = $('.accordian ul li');
$lis.hover(_hover,_out);
```

Finally you can write a simple script that automatize the carousel. Something like that:

```
var index = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $lis.removeClass('hover'); // remove previous hover
    $lis.parent().removeClass('hover');
    _hover.call($lis[index]); // set the jQuery element as context
    index = (index+1)%$lis.length; // increment or back to 0
},1400);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nctfa/27/

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong. I want to automatically change the highlighted picture while i am not hovering it (like this: link ). Is it possible, to do that without affecting the img tags at all?